# KARATE: lowerCaseResponseHeaders set to true put parameters' value in redirect_uri in lower case too

Tags: karate

I would like to use `karate.configure('lowerCaseResponseHeaders', true)` for one of test environments. But the problem is that it puts in lower case a state's value in redirect_uri which is returned in `responseHeaders.location` of a POST request. Example:

returned value for location:

```
location: https://www.example.com/bar?state=ReturnedValueForState
```

value set to lower case with `karate.configure('lowerCaseResponseHeaders', true)`

```
location: https://www.example.com/bar?state=returnedvalueforstate
```

I have to use the original returned value, otherwise I get a 404 Not Found when I use the redirect_uri. 
Is there a solution in karate to skip items' value in responseHeaders and put only items' names in lower case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to deal with this but it doesn't work for other responseHeaders. Here is my solution: in karate-config.js I put

- `location: 'location'` as environment variable for one which returns location in lower case
- `location: 'Location'` for an environment which return location in upper case. Then in features I can get location's value: `

  ```
   * def location = responseHeaders[location][0]`
   * def foo = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 2)
  ```

  It doesn't work for headers such as `PSU-User-Agent`. The response is `Could not parse token starting at position 1. Expected ?, ', 0-9, *`

I read here about this problem but didn't find any issue:  https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/504.

We use the latest karate version: 0.9.4.

Why in karate responseHeaders checks stay case sensitive? while in http protocol it should be case insensitive.
   Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Peter Thomas, we need and use karate for automation. This point really blocks us, we have to double the same features to adapt for different environments. Do you have any idea? please

Answer (score 1):

No. So do it manually. Use [`karate.lowerCase()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-lowercase) before you need to do a validation.

EDIT: this should be fixed, in the latest versions, `configure lowerCaseResponseHeaders` will only affect the header keys and not values.

Comment: I can't put `karate.lowerCase()`before the validation, because on some environments responseHeaders items are not in lower case. That's why I used `karate.configure('lowerCaseResponseHeaders', true)` to set it for the whole environment.

Comment: @nirind the reason you do `lowerCaseResponseHeaders` is if you want to validate some header key-values. otherwise just switch it off. what I am saying is switch it off. and if you are actually doing some checks, take the `responseHeaders` variable and deal with it manually. makes sense ?